# Generate 3-letter strings with FactoryGirl/Faker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, faker

I would like to generate random, unique strings matching this pattern: `[A-Z]{3}`. How can I achieve this with FactoryGirl or Faker?

I thought about FactoryGirl's sequences, but can't make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've ended up with:

```
sequence(:code) { ('A'..'Z').to_a.sample(3).join }
```

Comment: Does this guarantee uniqueness?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :str do |n|
    (0..2).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join
  end
end

FactoryGirl.generate :str # => "GUW"
```

Comment: @victorkohl: +1 for watershed :)

Answer (score 2):

There is option:

```
Faker::Name.initials(3)
```